# Syncing data in Android app

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an app that syncs different data through JSON in almost every Activity. This data could be manipulated by other devices so I have to keep it updated whenever possible.

For example, in the first Activity I login to the webservice, and in the next Activity I use AsyncTask to download a JSON that tells me all car models in the store, and use that info to create a ListView. Clicking on one row, I call another AsyncTask to download specific information (JSON) about that car, and get for example information about it's tires. In the next activity I'm calling another AsyncTask to get specific info about those tires. Most of the time, required info to be used in the next Activity is stored in SharedPreferences, because I have no idea how to have ArrayLists accessible in the entire app, and I don't know if it's going to utilize a lot of RAM. And if it is a good idea to share so many objects through the app.

You can see that everytime my Activity is reloaded, the AsyncTask checks the connection and download new data to be displayed. The service doesn't support push so I guess I have the responsibility to check it every time, correct?

Another thing to consider is that data downloaded can be changed and in that case, I have to upload the JSON, and refresh the views accordingly. In this aspect I have no idea how to save "changes" to be uploaded when the connection is down. Like, creating a queued list of unsynced tasks.

The result is an app that is heavily dependent on the internet connectivity and feels slow every time an Activity is resumed.

For most part I instantiate a new ArrayList of objects (Car, Tires, etc), but I'm confused how to properly sync data back in JSON if everything is now an object. Maybe using GJON?

I really need some tips about how to manage apps like this.

Thanks

Comment: Don't use `AsyncTask`s to talk to your web service. See the Google IO talk on developing REST client applications (http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/developing-RESTful-android-apps.html) and a library called Robospice (https://github.com/octo-online/robospice) for an implementation based on that talk.

Comment: @TylerTreat Thank you very much, I'm going to watch that session now! I hope it gives me some light., Although I'm usually afraid of using 3rd-party libs and have my a lot of dependencies in my project.

Comment: @TylerTreat thanks Tyler I'm also watching this now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just my thoughts quickly. as I have 2 very similar apps... ie, quite tightly coupled to an online service/database.

You really need to have a local database using sqlite.

Here is an example of how i suggest you handle each activity which is currently downloading data from the server to display:

1) What you can do is each time a screen loads, such as "`ListCarsActivity`" when `onResume()` runs you need to firstly call your local DB, get your most recent data, then display these results to screen, in your `ListView` etc. This will give quicker feedback to the user.

2) Following this, in `onResume()` you need to call a WebService object say `WSGetCars` which will kickoff a `Async` task to **A)** connect to the server, download the JSON/XML, parse the data and update the database (either Add or update etc) **B)** via a helper object with access to the activity re-run the database call, to refresh the list with fresh data.

in short:

1. load screen, and fill list with local FAST database list of cars
2. immediately and asynchronously download updated car data and sync the local db
3. refresh car list.

you can use this principle throughout your app.

whether you use my suggestion of a Web Service object is up to you. But i generally have Activity which calls a WS object to download which then utilises a XML parsing object etc etc.

Hopefully this helps on a conceptual level

**NOTE:** you will also require a simple IF statement around each WS/Async call so the app does not attempt connecting to the server unless you have internet connectivity. Allowing your app to appear still working when "offline" (be it, with possibly outdated data).

Regarding login screen: You can use `SharedPreferences` to check if they're already logged in each time onResume() loads, if logged in then auto load an internal page of the system. My app's will NOT allow logging in without internet connectivity. So this allows the app to still work if, in the last state they were already logged in.

Comment: Thank you a lot for sharing that! Your suggestion clarified and gave me ideas to work and improve, and it could be perfect if summed with the session/3rd-party library recommended above by @TylerTreat.

Comment: @user2129147 no problem at all. I've basically given you a the idea on what needs to be done, but as Tyler suggests. you could use RESTFul principles to get your local database data sync'd. This is as an alternative to what i currently do where i have a Async task download XML and update the database. But i think the goal is the same... ie, an updated Database, which you pull data from directly INSTEAD of forcing the user to wait for HTTP connections to download JSON. hope that makes sense